# Accessing FAT32 and NTFS format USB Pendrive from android tablet

Tags: android, usb, ntfs, fat32

We have a USB port in our android tablet(version 4.0.3).

Pendrive File Systems Format are

1. NTFS
2. FAT32

When Pendrive File Systems Format are `FAT32` File has been created Successfully. But When File Systems Format are `NTFS`, I got the Error Message as `open failed: EACCESS (Permission denied)`.

I Need to create a New File from in the USB Pendrive. I have tried my sample code is

```
Button createFile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.createFile);
createFile.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        try 
        {
            File root = new File("/mnt/usbhost1");
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + root.getAbsolutePath());
            File myFile = new File(root,"createNew.txt");
            myFile.createNewFile();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done Creating File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

Here `/usbhost1` is a Android tablet USB Path. Where I am mistaken. How to create a New File from in the `NTFS` File Systems Format.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Bala

Comment: the linux kernel in android supports fat 32 not ntfs you will have to use 3rd party progs to handle that

Comment: @droidhot How to use 3rd party(specified which application) programs to my application. How to create a New File(NTFS) using my application.

Comment: refer this its not simple it will be a good start up i ll inform you if i find something usefull http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1724078

Comment: Please tell me about... Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a way to enable support for NTFS in the kernel on your device. This could be achieved dynamically by building the ntfs-driver as loadable module (.ko file). This would need to be done for the specific version of the kernel that is running on your device.

Next you need a way to automatically load the module each time the systems restarts. this is also "do-able" in Android. You might want to try this [**app**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1228605) which does precisely that. i.e. load one or more kernel module(s) located anywhere on the Android device.

After this whenever one inserts a external-device(usb-drive) that has ntfs partitions, the kernel will be able to properly recognise and mount it. Hence apps can then access it at its proper location like "/mnt/usbhost1" etc.